# How to measure the ratio of a sand cement water mix for countertops

Tags: concrete, countertops, cement

I want to cast a concrete Countertop and I created several test batches.
I am confused by what I read and need some double checking.

I use a mixture of 
1 Part Cement 
2 Part Sand and 
0.4 Part Water (weight ratio related to the Cement) 
and 1.3% plasticizer (ADVA CAST 555)

Here is in detail what I mixed:

8 Liter Sand   ->  13 kg

4 Liter Cement ->  5.448 kg

Plasticizer 1.3% of 5.448 kg = 72 gr approx 72 ml (max)

So far all is ok the confusion starts with the water.

What I read the water is measured as a weight ratio 
related to the cement only, that should not exceed 0.5 
(better 0.4).

That would mean in my case 0.4 * 5.448 kg = 2.18 kg = 2.18 Liter

Can somebody confirm that this is all correct? Thx...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best ratio for sand-only concrete?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90389/whats-the-best-ratio-for-sand-only-concrete)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The emphasis is on the water calculation.